# Scrolling a div with full size that is within overflow hidden content

Tags: layout, html, scroll, overflow

I feel unhappy asking this, because this would've been beaten to death already. But, but, I am hoping it is not the same folks that answered elsewhere are seeing this one.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#bo{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#c1{
    float:top;
    height:40px;
    background:#ddd;
}

#c2{
    background:#ccc;
    height:100%;
}

#c3{
    float:left;
    background:#bbb;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
}

#c5{
    overflow:auto;
    height:400px; /* this should be page size.*/
}

#c6
{
    height:1000px;
    background:white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bo">
    <div id="c1"></div>
    <div id="c2">
        <div id="c3">
                <div id="c5">
                    <div id="c6">I want this to be page size.
                   </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="c4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the c5 div to have a scrollbar that fits the page size. If I give a fixed height, I get the scrollbar.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have scroll for a particular block, there is always a specific/fixed height with the overflow:auto property defined in the css, so that if the text goes beyond the defined height, the scroll should come. Which other option you are trying to have?

Comment: Okay, may be I am not asking it right; could you try the above in the browser, I have added some more detail.

Comment: well.. It is displaying the scroll at my end.

Comment: Now can you make the white part as large as the page size. I mean it has to be 1000px in height but should get a scrollbar.